# Return unique rows based on one column

Tags: sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008...

I have this result set:

```
ID        Name
------------------
717892    John
717892    Bill
717892    Steve
717200    Mark
717340    Gerald
717340    Frank
```

Here is what I want:

```
ID        Name
------------------
717892    John
717200    Mark
717340    Frank
```

I don't care which specific rows are returned, I just need to see the unique rows **based on the ID column**.

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, * FROM #tempTable;
```

But I get the following error:

```
The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: SELECT ID,MAX(Name) FROM table GROUP BY id

Comment: Don't use TEXT for a Name column. TEXT is deprecated (use varchar(MAX) or similar instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT ID,Name,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by name) as row
From tableName
)

Select ID,Name
FROM cte
Where row=1
```